# Use a trigger to stop an insert or update

Tags: mysql, triggers

Since MySQL ignores check constraints, how does one go about using a trigger to stop an insert or update from happening?

For example:

Table foo has an attribute called agency, and the agency attribute can only be 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger agency_check
before insert on foo
for each row
begin
if (new.agency < 1 or new.agency > 5) then

#Do nothing?

end if;
end
$$
delimiter ;
```

Or is there a better way to go about doing check constraints in MySQL?

Comment: Why can't you use `enum` datatype for agency column ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the SIGNAL syntax - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

```
create trigger agency_check
before insert on foo
for each row
begin
  if (new.agency < 1 or new.agency >5) then
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'your error message';
  end if 
end
```

**EDIT**

Updated based on popular comment below by Bill Karwin.

Comment: That's not correct syntax for `SIGNAL`. It should be `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'your error message';`

Answer (score 5):

If your version of MySQL is older than 5.5, try setting a non-null field of the table to NULL.  It is a hack, but it does prevent the update or insert from completing.

The SIGNAL command which Naveen suggests looks great, and I'm looking forward to using it after we upgrade.

Comment: I encountered one situation where setting the non-null field wasn't preventing the insert.  What has worked consistently for me (in Mysql 5.0 -- before SIGNAL is available) is to call a non-existent procedure.
[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1643846/109581) from [longneck](http://stackoverflow.com/users/94475/longneck) is where I got the tip to use CALL.