# Good security in MySQL web application: Root? Not Root?

Tags: mysql, security

Suppose you're writing a simple database web application using Ruby and MySQL. Access to the database is controlled by Ruby code. The user name that the Ruby code uses to access the data is the only regular user on the database. Does it make sense for that user to be "root"? Or is there any extra security in creating a second user just for the application?

Comment: Consider this alternate version of your question: "Is Ruby inherently safe so I can trust my code to never fail and give an attacker access to the database?"

Comment: But if I don't trust my Ruby code, I'm hosed anyway. Yeah, if it's not root, it can't delete my database, but it can still destroy all the data *in* the database. Not a big improvement.

Comment: Please read about the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

Comment: @Ami I applaud the principle, but I want to know what *known* security holes I'm closing by not granting my Ruby app superuser access. Without superuser access it can access or destroy all my data. What additional dangers are there that I should worry about?

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch: It's not about the known holes. In-depth security means that you have several lines of defense, so that when one breaks, you have at least one more to give you time to fix the broken one, or at least contain the damage. So you have an SQL injection vulnerability, but maybe it's in a part of the code that is only allowed to `SELECT`, and doesn't have access to the `credentials` table. That's a big plus - the attacker can now download regular data at will, but she cannot alter anything, nor gain access by reading password data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, consider the root as the main user, who can do everything (by default).

If he wants to dump the whole database, he can, if he wants to create some data to create (for example) fake account to overpass your bank system, he can.
So if your code is not enough secure (and this is quite often usually), you have strong security issue.

Usually, "a basic" security (really basic), should looks like that :
create a simple user, give him (with GRANTS) the right to SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on a specific database.

create another user who can SELECT and lock tables and SHOW VIEWS to perform dump (database save).

On a more "complex" system, you should create many users, depending of what they should access, this is for simple reason : if somebody got a SQL injection access, if the user can only access to a single view (for example), and not the whole database, this is a security issue but not the baddest one...
Also view are often used for that...

And finally don't forget triggers if you want (for example a log table), to disable insert or update or delete on a table, for everybody (except somebody who can destroy trigger of course) :
[Use a trigger to stop an insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168408/use-a-trigger-to-stop-an-insert-or-update)

Comment: If my "basic" user can delete, he can destroy all the data in my database. If he can select, he can see all the data.  Yeah, the structure of the database is safe if the user is not superuser, but the application itself is wide open. So if my Ruby code isn't secure, I'm hosed no matter what my user priviliges are.

Answer (score 4):

Besides editing or deleting all data in your database, the root user also have the [FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege which gives access to:

- `LOAD DATA INFILE` which can be used to read any file on the server machine.
- `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` which can read files on the client machine (the web server machine).
- `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` which can create files on the server machine.

This is why your application should have only the privileges it needs, and this is also the reason your MySQL server daemon should be run as a non-privileged user on the server machine.

See also [General Security Issues](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/general-security-issues.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

If everybody/thing is root, you lose auditability, you lose the ability to restrict the app to stop attacks (i.e. your app doesn't need this segment of sensitive information, seal it away from its user). If somebody compromises the app, you can suspend the account etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would *not* make a user "root".

I'd create a separate username and password just for that application and GRANT it only the permissions required to do its job.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new user, giving it only the permissions it needs (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE usually do the trick). Like that, you limit the ability for the code to be manipulated in an unintended way.

Answer (score 0):

"root", or generally speaking, users with Super User privileges, can change passwords, delete accounts, and therefore prevent you from accessing your own database.

If you server hosts only one application, then you may not need to create several lesser privileged accounts. However, it is common practice to create at least one user for each application, so that if one application gets compromised, other applications (and underlying data) may not be.