# MySQL insert multi records if not exist without unique column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert multiple records with single command, I can add them using something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES ("3","SHP","43-23"),("4", "KL", "54")
```

I can add multiple records but now I want to insert only if the record is not already present in that table. Tables are created dynamically and I'm not allowed to add any unique column, so I tried this to insert if not exist:

```
INSERT INTO b_branches (
     branch_name, branch_town, account_range_lower, account_range_upper
     ) SELECT
     'test BN'  branch_name,
     'test BT'    branch_town,
     'test ARL'    account_range_lower,
     'test ARU' account_range_upper
     FROM DUAL
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM `b_branches`
     WHERE
     branch_name = 'test BN' AND branch_town = 'test BT' AND account_range_lower = 'test ARL'
     LIMIT 1 -- will stop mysql to stop searching after first match
     )
```

This code works but through this I can add only one record at a time but I want to add all records in one statement. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: what? unable to understand

Comment: Mihai - you're wrong, from dual is legal for mysql too

Comment: @TheRaaaZ are you able to add indexes on your db ? or can you able to add unique index ?

Comment: @heximal first time i hear..you are correct

Comment: all tables create dynamically from csv or access files and are not allowed to be modified

Comment: Trigger before insert if new=old and new=old....

Comment: @Mihai can you please give a full detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a trigger.
But the only way that I know of to [stop an *Insert* within a trigger is to cause a *signal*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168408/use-a-trigger-to-stop-an-insert-or-update), which will rollback the whole commit.

Comment: is there any other way around? I'm unable to understand this one