# Make a trigger to prevent inserting same data on different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like some help please.
I created three tables as shown below, one TRACK, one COMPOSER and one ARTIST, And I want to crate a constraint that prevents from inserting a composer that already is an artist and vice-versa.
So I want to create a trigger that when I insert a new composer that already is in artist as shows an error message and if I insert an artist that is in composer shows the same.
I hope I as clear. Please help me

```
create table track (
 title varchar (255),
 number integer,
 duration interval,
 primary key (title, number)
 foreign key (title) references band (title)
);

create table composer (
 title varchar (255), 
 number integer, 
 name varchar (255), 
 primary key (title, number, name) 
 foreign key (title, number) track references (title, number) 
 foreign key (name) references person (name)
);


create table artist (
 title varchar (255),
 number integer,
 name varchar (255),
 primary key (title, number, name)
 foreign key (title, number) track references (title, number)
 foreign key (name) references person (name)
);
```

Comment: 1) Are you using mysql or are you using ms sql-server, you probably should not have tags for both. 2) How do you determine a duplicate, based on ID or Name -- mutliple people can can the same name. 3) You probably should not have this design in the first place. People often start as artists, then become composers, or vice versa. Often they are both for the same song. You should probably have an 'artist' table and then logically artist role such as 'composer', 'vocal', 'instrumental', 'lyrics' would apply to a given track/artist combination. Note that such a redesign eliminates your issue.

Comment: What you want to do is stop an insert from happening, right? Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168959/1106371 - Or consider what @GaryWalker said (;

Comment: I think @GaryWalker hit the nail in the head. Although I wouldn't call it artist then. Giving it a slightly more general name, and you can also store the mixers and even the marketing guys in your database, by just adding extra roles.

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong tags I just foun out that I'm using PostgreSQL. The duplicate must be determined with the keys title and number that are associated to track. The tables must have this design is for to know if tr track was made for one artist or one composer but can't be done by both and and an artist cn't be a composer.

Comment: (Edofsource) The problem is making the trigger to test if the same title and number is already in the other table and if the same trigger can test that on both tables