# Oracle vs MySQL in context

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

So, I'm aware this isn't exactly a programming question but I felt it was still appropriate.

What is the difference between Oracles proprietary RDBMS, that they license, vs MySQL, an open source DBMS they bought? Performance? Support? Security? Features?

Also, I read MySQL isn't SQL complaint, yet it is compatible with the SQL language. What am I missing?

Comment: "Not SQL-compliant" means it doesn't support *everything* in the SQL standard. Few databases do. It still supports *most* standard SQL features.

Comment: Oracle isn't ANSI compliant either.  Just consider that `'' is null` evaluates to true!  @Wyzard is correct, all databases have their peculiarities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports SQL, but doesn't support all features of SQL. Most databases implement a part of the SQL standard and a bunch of extra features. If a database implements everything of the standard, then queries following those standards are usable in all those databases (provided the table structure is the same. But both Oracle and MySQL implement most of those features.

More info about MySQL sql compliancy: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/compatibility.html

Oracle also provides a comparison between MySQL and Oracle here, which is mainly a summary of technical differences and doesn't compare the big picture: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm

A more high-level comparison can be found here: http://www.rapidprogramming.com/questions-answers/What-is-the-difference-between-MySQL-and-Oracle--617
The main conclusion there seems to be that Oracle has more features on an enterprise level, like better tools, better support for stored procedures, better analytical features, and better user management. All in all Oracle is more a large data warehouse/enterprise level database, while MySQL is good for hosting websites, can scale quite well, but wouldn't be a primary choice for building a data warehouse in. Those features of Oracle come at a price, of course.

Answer (score 0):

One big difference is that MySQL does not support CHECK constraints, which is an important part of maintaining database integrity.

See here for an example that you cannot use under MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877154/8454

Also, please don't think that Oracle and MySQL are your only two choices.  PostgreSQL is also open source like MySQL but far more featureful (and supports CHECK constraints).  http://www.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that most production motor vehicles are certified to be roadworthy, most SQL implementations are "SQL compatible".  Beyond that, there are a lot of differences.  Like scalability, performance, features, language extensions and how to access the internals (like listing all tables in a database).  They all can do the job, but a Chevy Malibu might not be the best choice for the Indy 500.