# add unique constraint but enforce it only for new insertions

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql INNODB table with 3 columns

```
id  |    col1    | col2
```

id is the primary key.

The table contains rows where the pair (col1, col2) is repeated more than once.

Can I create an unique index on (col1, col2) which only enforces the uniqueness on the addition of future rows but allows the existing rows where the pair (col1, col2) is repeated more than once.

I tried executing:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint UNIQUE (col1, col2)
```

but got an error:
    Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'myconstraint'

Comment: write your own storage engine :)

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to go through the effort, you could add a new column called something like `NullIfOld`.  Set this column to a constant value for new insertions and to `NULL` for the old records.

Then create a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_mytable_col1_col2_nullifold on mytable(col1, col2, nullifold);
```

A unique index allows multiple rows with `NULL` values, so you can create the index.  If the new values are a constant (or even something like `concat(col1, col2)`), then new unique records will be disallowed.

Comment: Suppose I add this new column and now this row exists in the table (col1,col2,NullIfOld) = (1,1,null). But, it will still let me insert (1,1,1) but yes, from that point onwards, it won't let me insert it again.

Comment: @user674669 . . . Until you change the value to `NULL`, it won't allow you to insert another active record.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: no, you can't.
But you could explore triggers on insert and accomplish your task with a stored procedure.

A starting point: http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168959/2898712

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility to

1. Create a new column, eg. `legacy_id`, to mark the difference between old and new rows. It should have a default value, say `1`.

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD legacy_id bigint(20) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL;
   ```
2. Update all existing rows to set the value of `legacy_id` to that of `id`

   ```sql
   UPDATE mytable SET legacy_id=id;
   ```
3. Create a unique index on `legacy_id, col1, col2`

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT myconstraint UNIQUE KEY (legacy_id,col1,col2);
   ```

Now, you have your unique index. Every new row will have the same value for legacy, i.e. `1`.

It will not be possible to create a new row with the same value for `col1` and `col2` - except if you explicitly set a value of `legacy_id` (to something different from `1`).