# MySQL - Only increment/no change a status field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that I would really appreciate some help with.  I have a MySQL column named status.  The status should never go down on update, but rather stay the same if I try to update it to a lower number (via update query).  Is there a setting I can set on the table to never allow it to update the status field, if it is lower than the current status.

Name, Status
ex: test Person, 8

update 'db' set status '6' where name = "test person"
(error or doesn't update)

If it is not possible in a setting SQL, What would be the way in PHP in order to accomplish this?

Comment: `where name="test person" and status <= 6`? That an `on update` trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168408/use-a-trigger-to-stop-an-insert-or-update

Comment: Yep. Trigger. You'll set it `before update for each row` and throw an exception if `NEW.status < OLD.status`.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me, Im very close.  I have did this one, but cannot get it to work with MySQL.

create trigger test
BEFORE UPDATE on foo
for each row
begin
  IF(new.status < old.status) THEN
    SIGNAL 'Nope';
  END IF
END
$$
delimiter ;

Getting an Error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Nope'' at line 6

Comment: may I know your table structure and your update query ?

Comment: sure the structure is name - varchar(99), status int(11)
update 'db' set status = 10 where name = 'something'