# Require column in MySQL safe update

Tags: mysql, safe-mode

I have a MySQL server with safe mode enabled (on purpose). Lets say a table looks like this:

```
id | name | color | id_team
 1 | a    | red   |       1
 2 | b    | red   |       2
 3 | c    | green |       1
```

When I query

```
UPDATE table SET name='d';
```

I get the expected error, that MySQL safe mode is turned on and updating requires a `WHERE` clause. Allright:

```
UPDATE table SET name='d' WHERE color='red';
```

... updates id 1 and 2.

Is it possible to define anything so that updating this table requires column `id_team` in the `WHERE` clause, independent from other `WHERE`-columns?

As you can probably guess, `id_team` is about permissions and I try to force everyone playing around on MySQL console to ensure that a specific column is set when updating.

Comment: You could use a trigger to prevent the insert happening. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168408/use-a-trigger-to-stop-an-insert-or-update

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like 'WHERE id > 0' but maybe it is time to turn off safe mode.