# Database System Help Please

Tags: database

Write a MySQL trigger that does not allow to change the population of the city, where the city
population is greater than the country population where it belongs ?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168408/use-a-trigger-to-stop-an-insert-or-update