# How can i create a trigger to verify if a record exists on another table?

Tags: mysql

I am using version 5.0 of mysql.

I'm trying to create a trigger to check if one entry(name of Food) exists in the other table.

I´ve done this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER verifyExists BEFORE INSERT ON Sold
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.nameF not in (
            select A.nameF
            From Available D
            where (NEW.nameF = A.nameF and NEW.nameR = A.nameR)
        )
        END IF;
    END;
//
delimiter ;
```

this doesen't work, why?

Comment: Your trigger doesn't actually do anything. Your `IF` has no `THEN`.

Comment: Isn't this what foreign key constraints are for?

Comment: now i have then but doesent work..
hobbs, i know that , but i need to create that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of errors:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER verifyExists BEFORE INSERT ON Sold
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.nameF not in (
            select A.nameF
            From Available A  -- CHANGED THE ALIAS TO A
            where (NEW.nameF = A.nameF and NEW.nameR = A.nameR)
        ) THEN -- MISSING THEN
           CALL `Insert not allowed`;

        END IF;
    END;
//
delimiter ;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/854f4)</kbd>

If you could use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html), it is the best way, but since it was only introduced in mysql 5.5, you will have to do it by other route. One way is to call a non existant function, like showed above. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643846/1385896)

Comment: when there is no name in the table i want to tell the user the problem and dont insert on table.. it's possible?

Comment: i've got this when trying to run:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter //CREATE TRIGGER verifyExists BEFORE INSERT ON Sold
    FOR EACH ROW
' at line 1

Comment: @user3046650. Yes. i saw after that you are using a version of mysql that does not support SIGNAL, which is the way to do this, but i added a way to cancel the insert. Try on sqlfiddle by inserting (2,2) in sold.

Comment: data base retrieve error 1305(42000) PROCEDURE Insert not aloowed doesent exists :/

i use Server version: 5.1.72-2-log (Debian)

Comment: @user3046650. That's the error you will get whenever you try to insert a value that is not allowed.

Comment: @user3046650. If you don't like that error message, you can search here on stackoverflow for other workarounds, but to cancel the insert, you will always have to use a workaround.

Comment: thank you filipe, i just didnt know that the message will always be that xd i must admit, i try a lot of solutions and i get that message many times, but i thought that was an error, but now you told me that the message was from the insert ;) ty again